# How do I use custom tools in a Bluemix DevOps pipeline stage

Tags: ibm-cloud, pipeline, devops, continuous-delivery

I want to use a custom build tool (e.g. installed with brew install or some such) in a stage of my BlueMix DevOps Services pipeline.  The doc says that each stage runs in a fresh container.  How do I get my tools loaded into that container for use in my pipeline stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new job in a stage, you can write a script to be executed. In this script, you can call `apt-get install`, `apt-get update` and so on.

As example:

```
#!/bin/bash
# your script here
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jq
jq --help
```

[image: Use a script to install dependencies]

I've used the script approach to install tools like *nvm* (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to use any Node.js version. You will need to reinstall the tools you want to use in any job that requires them.